# Why are application settings not consistently being persisted to config file?

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio-2013

I'd like to keep using Application Settings but I'm about to give up and implement my own solution.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, .Net 4.5 and the below happens regardless of whether I run my application within the IDE or run it as a standalone EXE.  I am not planning of ever installing my application; have not and will not create a setup for it.

In my Form_Load() event I have this code:

```
Settings boo = MyApp.Properties.Settings.Default;
boo.Reload();
boo.mystring = "baa";
boo.Save();
```

Once I step through these 4 lines, I will check boo.mystring and it will have the value "baa" as it should;

At this point, I can check my app.config file under %appdata%... and toss a coin, it may or may not have been updated

The mystery continues if I decide to let my program run and retry the same above 4 lines, minutes later, in another section of my code.  After doing a boo.Reload(), the setting: "boo.mystring", may or may not have retained its "baa" value.

Things I've checked:

- The IDE is running as Administrator.
- Administrator and my own account have Full Control to both my %appdata% folder AND my project folder,  including all their subfolders and files.
- This inconsistency will happen regardless of whether I use the above four lines of Application Settings in the same class or another class.
- It will also happen regardless of whether I try to use the above four lines of Application Settings back to back or by calling it from a button.
- I've used "boo.Upgrade()", doesn't fix the issue.
- I've checked many articles here and elsewhere about this issue, the fixes either revolve around making sure to use Reload(), Upgrade(), Save(), or imply that you need to run your EXE after you've created and run a setup for your application.

The issue has actually been going on for me for years across a few different computers, hard drives, windows versions, etc.

Now I'm at the point where I'm either going to get this to work as advertised, or will go through the pains of writing my own settings implementation.

Any fixes, pointers, suggestions or any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Comment: A tid bit of additional info:  I've been using "user" scope as opposed to "application" scope settings since the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be helpful:

http://www.geek-republic.com/2010/11/c-portable-settings-provider/

I used that code (as is) in a project of mine where I wanted the app settings to be the same from compile to compile, and also have them still able to be bound to controls. (It's a tool I use for development and it gets recompiled A LOT). Some settings are not bound to controls and are accessed at various times, much like your use case.

Here are some comments I made at the time about why I bothered using it:

> First note that app.config settings are either app-level or
>   user-level. App-level settings are read-only, so we must use
>   user-level settings for settings that need to be saved to the
>   app.config during runtime. Normal behavior from MS is to store
>   user-level settings in the user's AppData local folder.
>   PortableSettingsProvider saves user-level appSettings to the
>   app.config file located where the exe is located instead of into the
>   user's AppData local folder. Normally AppData is fine, but the author
>   wanted easily "portable" config files, i.e.,  everything in one place,
>   not fragmented into user's folders. This app wants this behavior for
>   development...every recompile put user config files into new folders.
>   This app wants the same file to be used from compile to compile.
>   Further, sticking with app settings rather than some other method
>   means that we can bind a control's property to an app setting using
>   the designer (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yyxh69h).

In any case, it "just works" for me, maybe something in this discussion will help you find your answer.

Comment: Hi Minnow, thank you for your info/suggestion.  I had a look at the portable provider and minus a few considerations peculiar to my implementation, for the most part, according to what I can see, I could use this alternative as a probable working solution.  However, I'm rather looking, still, for whatever may explain why my posted code snippet wouldn't be working, out of the box, as I think MS provided Application Settings should.